# How to determine if the byte array is all zero in java

Tags: java, arrays

I was having some problem when trying to loop thru byte array. Basically I got two nested for loop. The outer one will loop for 256 times, the inner one will loop for the first 8 bytes of byte array.

```
outerloop:
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
        // code

        byte [] first8bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, 0, 8);

        for(int k = 0; k < first8bytes.length; k++){
            if(k != 0){
            }else{
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(first8bytes));
                break outerloop;
            }
        }        
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to check if the first8bytes is all 0. If one of them is not zero, I will go back to the outerloop. However, by doing this, when I try to print out the first8bytes, the result is [-26, 0, -28, -49, 64, 45, 66, 66].

I am trying to get the first8bytes of all 0 before breaking out. I know something is really wrong with my logic but I have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Updated

```
boolean all0 = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    byte [] first8bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, 0, 8);
    for( int k = 0; k < first8bytes.length && all0; ++k ){
            if( first8bytes[k] != 0 ) all0 = false;
    }
    if(all0){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(first8bytes));
        break;
     }}
```

Comment: As soon as you find 1 byte that is 0 you print the array. In your example the 2nd byte is 0...

Comment: But how should I fix it? I know the logic is wrong, I even added boolean variable to try it out but it is resulting in the same

Comment: Are you really trying to check the same 8 bytes in `byteArray` 256 times?  Are you sure you don't want to be selecting a different range in the `byteArray` each time through the outer loop?  Right now I'm having a really hard time figuring out what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! So I have a str with 7 bytes, I wanted to append 256 ASCII as the 8 bytes and thus the outer loop. Then I will do some logic on the byte array. After that, I will extract out the first 8 bytes from the byte array. Then, I wanted to check if all the 8 bytes are 0. If all of them are 0, then I will perform some logic which I have not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I'd do it - write a method for the test:

```
boolean allZeros( byte[] bytes ){
    boolean all0 = true;
    for( int i = 0; i < bytes.length && all0; ++i ){
        if( bytes[i] != 0 ) all0 = false;
    }
    return all0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    // code

    if( allZeros( Arrays.copyOfRange(byteArray, 0, 8) ) ) break;

}
```

Comment: Sorry but let's say if I have to do it in one single method, can I just do what I did in the updated portion? I think my code got the boolean logic wrongly as I managed to eye-balling and find the match by printing out those details , but somehow when I tried to check if there is a single byte array with all 0, it is printing nothing

Comment: Breaking out of more than one level is almost always a code smell. If possible, terminate loops on conditions.